# Optimization and workarounds for loading and writing large files

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to realise two functions: `getState` saves the initial values and formulas of a workbook to JavaScript variables, `setState` restores initial formulas and values of a workbook from JavaScript variables. Normally, my add-in starts from executing `getState`, then do some operations that may change range formulas and values, and ends by executing `setState`.

**However, I realise that these functions may raise internal errors for large Excel files (where one worksheet may contain several thousands of rows).** For example,

[image]

Here are code snippets:

```
var usedRanges;

function getState () {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        usedRanges = [];
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
        var usedRangesLocal = [];
        worksheets.load('items');
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) { 
                    worksheets.items[i].load('name');
                    usedRangesLocal[i] = worksheets.items[i].getUsedRange();
                    usedRangesLocal[i].load(["address", "formulasR1C1", "values"]);
                }
            })
            .then(ctx.sync)
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    usedRanges.push({
                        sheet: worksheets.items[i].name,
                        address: usedRangesLocal[i].address,
                        formulasR1C1: usedRangesLocal[i].formulasR1C1,
                        values: usedRangesLocal[i].values
                    });
                }
            });
    });
}
```

and

```
function setState () {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
        worksheets.load('items');
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    var r = worksheets.items[i].getRange(usedRanges[i].address);
                    r.values = usedRanges[i].values
                    r.formulasR1C1 = usedRanges[i].formulasR1C1; 
                }
            });
    });
}
```

These are [Manifest_remote.xml](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/Manifest_remote.xml), [Home.html](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/Home.html) and [Home.js](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/Home.js). In Home.js, I try to do some workarounds by splitting loading of different properties, but the result is still not good.

So I test this add-in under `Excel Online` against different subsets of a large workbook. The tests show that, bigger a workbook is, more likely the functions fail (**especially `setState` takes a lot of time and is very likely to stuck, even under Excel Windows**) . Here are the three files: [GetNoAllNo.xlsx](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/GetNoAllNo.xlsx), [GetYesAllNo.xlsx](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/GetYesAllNo.xlsx) and
[GetYesAllYes.xlsx](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/GetYesAllYes.xlsx).

These xlsx files are realistic and not very large. So I really look for solutions or workarounds to make `getState` and `setState` work better.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link has valuable information on performance optimization for Office Add-Ins: http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization

The information on section **Design and implementation techniques** shall help solving this issue.